# How to Decompile an unknown packed .exe

Tags: decompiling, ida, ollydbg

I'm new to decompiling, so I'm sorry if I sound like an idiot.

Using Process Explorer I found out that the .exe I want to decompile is packed, and via PEiD it says "Nothing found *" . Due to it being packed, I am clueless on how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to ask questions about Reverse Engineering in its [suitable Stack Excahnge community](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

There are already existing questions in SE.RE that might help you:

- [Unpacking binaries in a generic way](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72/unpacking-binaries-in-a-generic-way)
- [Unpacking binary statically](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113/unpacking-binary-statically)

In a personal note, I'd suggest you to stop using PEiD since it is not maintaned for years. Check out [Detect It Easy](http://ntinfo.biz/index.html).